# google drive api client(python) update error

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-apis-explorer

not working only update function.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer
and good work same parameter on api explorer.
update file is from cloud domain file. is that reason?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/cygwin64/home/socia/workspace/language/python/wc_py2_rule/src/main/python/package_name/module/sotrage/google_folder_changer.py", line 230, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "E:/cygwin64/home/socia/workspace/language/python/wc_py2_rule/src/main/python/package_name/module/sotrage/google_folder_changer.py", line 101, in main
    set_seed_file_on_folder(file_info, folder, service)
  File "E:/cygwin64/home/socia/workspace/language/python/wc_py2_rule/src/main/python/package_name/module/sotrage/google_folder_changer.py", line 142, in set_seed_file_on_folder
    removeParents=file_info['parents']).execute()
  File "E:\cygwin64\home\socia\workspace\language\python\wc_py2_rule\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\cygwin64\home\socia\workspace\language\python\wc_py2_rule\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/... returned "File not found: [u'file_id'].">
```

file_id is replaced on error cause of security
and link content is below.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

> "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Means that you are making a call to a private method without authenticating as a user first.  If you want to see user data you must be authenticated as a user who has access to that data.  Check your code and make sure that you have your authentication setup correctly and the user has logged in before you try and run the method in question.